# Security "Crypto" provider deprecated in Android N

Tags: android

A user run my application in Android N, he got the crash.I know Google deprecated Crypto provider in Android N,but what would be the best way to migrating old encrypted data.

Answer (score 21):

For 8.0 and above you can refere  [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39002997/2897365)

For below 8.0 version you can go through following code.

You can use this provider replacing "Crypto" for SecureRandom, its working for me fine:

Use,

```
SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", new CryptoProvider());
```

instead of,

```
SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG","Crypto");
```

and your CryptoProvider class like as below,

```
import java.security.Provider;
/**
 * Implementation of Provider for SecureRandom. The implementation     supports the
 * "SHA1PRNG" algorithm described in JavaTM Cryptography Architecture, API
 * Specification & Reference
*/
public final class CryptoProvider extends Provider {
    /**
 * Creates a Provider and puts parameters
 */
public CryptoProvider() {
    super("Crypto", 1.0, "HARMONY (SHA1 digest; SecureRandom; SHA1withDSA signature)");
    put("SecureRandom.SHA1PRNG",
            "org.apache.harmony.security.provider.crypto.SHA1PRNG_SecureRandomImpl");
    put("SecureRandom.SHA1PRNG ImplementedIn", "Software");
}
}
```

Comment: I'm using this approach. However, my app gets crashed when I try to decrypt already encrypted data by old approach. Any solution to mitigate this issue?

Comment: @Amrut I face same problem. Can you help me? did you find the solution of this

Comment: The Crypto provider is completely removed in Android P. We're getting below exception if we're using the above solution - 
 java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for SecureRandom (provider: Crypto) cannot be found.

Comment: I have already facing this problem in Android P. Any solution to this issue?

Comment: Hello @PraveenKumarVerma please refer link i suggested into edited answer, it may help you for resolve issue of Android P.

Comment: Can any one provide link to solve this issue which is compatible with both android 8 and 9 Pie?

Comment: Hello, @BiswasKhayargoli have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/39002997/2897365 link?

Comment: getting error :  java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for SecureRandom (provider: Crypto) cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for provider :

```
SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1").getProvider();
```