# Crypto breaking Nougat change

Tags: android, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric

When researching why my encrypted messenger app would not work on Nougat I found [this document](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/security-crypto-provider-deprecated-in.html) that describes the breaking change and it's reasons along with some technical info on encryption using passwords.  This had not meaning for me as I don't use Passwords.  The document does not offer any complete examples on what to do so I began looking all over for what to do.

My research led me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097099/security-crypto-provider-deprecated-in-android-n/42337802). The answer to the post works but I have no idea why.  Furthermore the last comment says . . .
"At least this can be a quick-fix before actually going on the recommended way"

What is the "recommended way?"  Are there any working examples anywhere on the recommend way?

Comment: Post **your code**, we can't recommend a change without seeing what your code does.

Comment: If you're not using SecureRandom to generate deterministic keys then you shouldn't have a problem. If you are then 'ur doin' it rong™.

Comment: "What is the "recommended way?"" -- I presume they are referring to the code shown in [the Android Developers Blog post that you linked to](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/security-crypto-provider-deprecated-in.html). Or perhaps they are referring to [this older Android Developers Blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html). Or perhaps they are referring to [Nikolay Elenkov's blog post](https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/04/using-password-based-encryption-on.html).