# Removal of the Crypto provider - Android P API 28

Tags: android, android-security, android-api-levels

I'm using the Crypto provider in my application. I know that it is deprecated in Android N. However I used the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097099/security-crypto-provider-deprecated-in-android-n) and it was working perfectly fine.

Now in Android P (API 28), they've completely removed it [details here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/cryptography-changes-in-android-p.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-migration).

I'm getting below warnings in my logcat -

**W/System.err: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for SecureRandom (provider: Crypto) cannot be found.**

Please assist me with the solutions or any links which will lead me to the solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just don't use it. It has been deprecated for a reason, not just for fun. Stop trying to use it, and move to another provider

Comment: Related [Fix for Security “Crypto” on Nougat does not work for Pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799526/fix-for-security-crypto-on-nougat-does-not-work-for-pie)

Comment: @NileshRathod Do we've have any solution for this?